# SQL computed column - formula to calculate length and do a substring

Tags: sql-server, string

Hi I'm looking for a easier solution to one of the columns in SQL table. The column has a datatype of nvarchar(50). However, I want to put a formula in the **computed column** field of this column whereby:

- check if the length of the data being inserted is more than 50.
- If it is, then take the first 36 characters.
- create the string - "**[SQL-Truncated]…**"+"**the 34 characters from previous step**" ([SQL-Truncated]... is 16 characters in length.)
- insert this new string in that column instead, thereby ensuring we only get 50 chars.

Comment: Storing data like "[SQL-Truncated]…"+"something" exhibit bad DB design.you may contrite later.
Moreover,if your proc is new then you can write the logic in proc itself instead of computed column. Becasue performance may suffer because of computed column

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this: create a stored function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TrimLongerThan50(@Input NVARCHAR(500))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @Result = @Input

    IF LEN(@Input) > 50
        SET @Result = N'[SQL-Truncated] ' + SUBSTRING(@input, 1, 34)

    RETURN @result
END
```

and then use it in the computed column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD NewComputedColumn AS dbo.TrimLongerThan50(YourInputColumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

the formula isn't that complicated but i'm not quite sure if you really want to create a computed column.

```
alter table add mytruncatedtext 
  as ( case when len(origcolumn) > 50 
         then N'[SQL-Truncated] ' + left(origcolumn, 34) 
         else origcolumn 
     end )
  persisted
```